# Improve Tesseract result for scanned image

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have a processed scanned image which I am attempting to perform OCR on. The image looks like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmKnU.jpg) after converting it to binary and scaling it, however Tesseract is unable to retrieve the alphanumericals that stand out from the rest.

[Processed image to perform OCR on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmKnU.jpg)

The expected result would be "*123112*" but I am getting jibberish such as "*53";.gxuimSaabz'ssiiämFi”???
1231 12 5
*". 
Tessaract instantiated as follows through JNI (implemented in Java 8):

```
            instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
            instance.setLanguage("swe");
            instance.setOcrEngineMode(ITessAPI.TessOcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
```

Any ideas how I can improve the result?

Comment: It does look like you have the correct number in there "1231 12" so maybe it is parsing the top letters as gibberish because of noise. Try telling Tesseract to only match digits, or try reducing the noise by doing an erosion followed by a dilation to remove small single pixels.

Comment: Yes my expected numbers does indeed show but the result is very unpredictable as it changes from time-to-time. I will try reducing noise further, thanks for the tip!